# Validation not getting triggered when value is changed

Tags: aurelia

In Aurelia project, I have created a bootstrap modal that will allow users to enter email addresses. At first when the pop-up is triggered, it applies the validation fine. See below image. This is how it looks like when the pop-up is opened for the first time.

[image]

Once you enter the validate email address and click on `add` `btn`, I am resetting the value of `this.setEmail` to `""` an empty string. So that way users can type new email address to add. But the validation rule that shows the message `Email is required` is no longer getting triggered. See below example:

[image]

See the [Plunker link here](https://plnkr.co/edit/49Kmqf?p=info). Once the page is loaded. Click on the `+` icon next to email input. It will open a bootstrap modal.

Below is the code and can be seen at above link as well:

**email.ts**

```
import { customElement, useView, bindable, bindingMode, inject, observable } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { ValidationRules, ValidationControllerFactory, Validator } from 'aurelia-validation';

@inject(ValidationControllerFactory)
@customElement('email')
@useView('./email.html')
export class Email {
  @bindable public modalName: string;
  @bindable public modalValue: string;
  @bindable public emailAddress: string;
  public emailAddresses = [];
  @observable public setEmail: string;
  public errorMessage: string;
  emailController = null;

  constructor(factory) {
    this.setEmail = '';
    this.emailController = factory.createForCurrentScope();
    ValidationRules.ensure('setEmail')
        .displayName('Email')
        .required()
        .email()
        .on(this);
  }

  public bind() {
    this.emailController.validate();
  }

  private joinEmails() {
    this.emailAddress = this.emailAddresses.join(";");
  }

  private isUniqueEmail = (email: string) => {
    return (this.emailAddresses.indexOf(email) === -1)
  }

  public addEmail() {
    if (this.setEmail) {
      if(!this.isUniqueEmail(this.setEmail))
      {
        this.errorMessage = "You must provide unique email address.";
        return;
      }
      this.emailAddresses.push(this.setEmail);
      this.joinEmails();
      this.setEmail = '';
    }
    else
    {
      this.errorMessage = "You must provide an email address."
    }
  }

  public setEmailChanged(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log({oldValue: oldValue, newValue: newValue});
  }

  public removeEmail(index) {
    this.emailAddresses.splice(index, 1);
    this.joinEmails();
    console.log(this);
  }
}
```

**email.html**

```
<template>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="${modalName}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add Email Address</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" id="setEmail" name="setEmail" class="form-control" value.bind="setEmail & validateOnChangeOrBlur" />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-primary"
                      disabled.bind="emailController.errors.length > 0" 
                      click.delegate="addEmail()">Add
              </button>
            </span>
          </div>
          <input type="text" value.bind="emailAddress" hidden />
          <span class="text-danger" repeat.for="error of emailController.errors">${error.message}</span>
          <span class="text-danger" if.bind="errorMessage">${errorMessage}</span>
          <div>
            <ul class="list-group" if.bind="emailAddresses.length > 0" style="margin-top: 10px;">
              <li class="list-group-item" repeat.for="e of emailAddresses">
                ${e} <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-danger pull-right" style="cursor: pointer;" click.delegate="removeEmail($index)"></span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: plunk not found.

Comment: Thats weird. Here is the updated link: https://plnkr.co/edit/49Kmqf?p=info. will update my post as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `addEmail()` function after the line `this.setEmail = '';` call the validate again with `this.emailController.validate();`

The `validate()` method returns a `Promise` so you may want to handle any rejections as you would normally see this section of the validation docs  [Validation Controller](http://aurelia.io/docs/plugins/validation#validation-controller) specifically the sub section 'validate & reset'.

I'm guessing you expected this to happen automatically because of the 2-way binding and the `validateOnChangeOrBlur` binding behavior the reason it didn't is that the JavaScript setting the value doesn't trigger DOM events so you need to manually call or fire a synthetic event.

Comment: Aquila, thank you for your response. I was able to trigger validation by adding `this.emailController.validate();` after `this.setEmail = '';`. You are right. I was hoping that `validateOnChangeOrBlur` would take care of it for me. Thanks for clarifying for me.

Comment: @Ray Aquila already eluded this but didn't explicitly mention it: `validateOnChange` means it validates on the `change` event of the element, not when the value of the targeted property changes. The docs say this on the trigger: "Validate the binding when it updates the model due to a change in the view."

Comment: Thanks Fred for clarifying. :)